# Error connecting to aws redshift using dask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, dask

I am using `dask` to connect to AWS Redshift and query the db. I run into an error when attempting to pass a connection string to `read_sql_query` method.

`config.py`

```
import os

# Create dictionary of environment variables
env_var_dict = {
                    # Amazon Redshift
                    'host':'xxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                    'database':'db1',
                    'port':'5439',
                    'user':'user1',
                    'password':'xxxxx'

               }


# set environment variables
os.environ['host'] = env_var_dict['host']
os.environ['database'] = env_var_dict['database']
os.environ['port'] = env_var_dict['port']
os.environ['user'] = env_var_dict['user']
os.environ['password'] = env_var_dict['password']




# connect to aws redshift cluster
import redshift_connector
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    
     host=os.environ['host'],
     database=os.environ['database'],
     port=int(os.environ['port']),
     user=os.environ['user'],
     password=os.environ['password']
     
  )

import sqlalchemy as sa
host=os.environ['host'],
database=os.environ['database'],
port=int(os.environ['port']),
user=os.environ['user'],
password=os.environ['password']

conn_str = f'redshift+redshift_connector://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'

# dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

"redshift+redshift_connector://('user',):pwd@hostname,):('5439',)/('tracking',)"

# Query table using dask dataframe
query = '''
        SELECT * 
        FROM tbl
        WHERE type = 'xxx'
        and created_at >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00'
        and created_at <= '2023-12-01 00:00:00'
        '''

df = dd.read_sql_query(query, conn_str, index_col = 'id')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "('5439',)"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2539550446659032>:10
      1 # Query table using dask dataframe
      2 query = '''
      3         SELECT * 
      4         FROM pmf
   (...)
      7         and created_at <= '2023-12-01 00:00:00'
      8         '''
---> 10 df = dd.read_sql_query(query, conn_str, index_col = 'id')

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py:107, in read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, divisions, npartitions, limits, bytes_per_chunk, head_rows, meta, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
    104     raise TypeError("Must supply either 'divisions' or 'npartitions', not both")
    106 engine_kwargs = {} if engine_kwargs is None else engine_kwargs
--> 107 engine = sa.create_engine(con, **engine_kwargs)
```

I have tried to pass `port` as `int` and `str`. How do I connect to aws redshift and run a query in dask?

Answer (score 1):

This connection string

```
"redshift+redshift_connector://('user',):pwd@hostname,):('5439',)/('tracking',)"
```

sure does look wrong! Perhaps it should be

```
"redshift+redshift_connector://user:pwd@hostname:5439/tracking"
```

It seems that all of your variables passed into your f-string are tuples rather than simple values (str/int). Since you didn't say how you specified these values, it is hard to help, but it could be as simple as stray commas in your code.

Specifically: change

```
host=os.environ['host'],
database=os.environ['database'],
port=int(os.environ['port']),
user=os.environ['user'],
```

to

```
host=os.environ['host']
database=os.environ['database']
port=int(os.environ['port'])
user=os.environ['user']
```

Comment: I have the updated the post with how I am setting the environment variables.

Comment: edited to highlight the stray commas, as suspected.